# Spark map is only one task while it should be parallel (PySpark)

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, pyspark

I have a RDD with around 7M entries with 10 normalized coordinates in each. I also have a number of centers and I'm trying to map every entry to the closest (Euclidean distance) center. The problem is that this only generates one task which means it is not parallelizing. This is the form:

```
def doSomething(point,centers):
    for center in centers.value:
        if(distance(point,center)<1):
             return(center)
    return(None)

preppedData.map(lambda x:doSomething(x,centers)).take(5)
```

The preppedData RDD is cached and already evaluated, the doSomething function is represented a lot easier than it actually is but it's the same principle. The centers is a list that has been broadcast. Why is this map only in one task?

Similar pieces of code in other projects just map to +- 100 tasks and get run on all the executors, this one is 1 task on 1 executor. My job has 8 executors with 8 GB and 2 cores per executor available.

Comment: How many tasks do you get if you force going through all entries, for instance with `preppedData.map(lambda x:doSomething(x,centers)).count()`? How many partitions does your RDD have (`preppedData.getNumPartitions()`)?

Comment: How big is your file with 7M entries?

Comment: sgvd that might have fixed it, but usually it still partitions it correctly when I use a small `take`. I will check the number of partitions tomorrow.

Comment: Radu, I don't know, it's not from a file, it's from a relatively big pipeline. It has 2 identifying columns, 3 columns with lists ranging from length 1 up to 1000 (most of them small) and then the 10 coordinates that I feed to the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be due to the conservative nature of the take() method. 
[See the code in RDD.scala.](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1201)

What it does is first take the first partition of your RDD (if your RDD doesn't require a shuffle, this will require only one task) and if there are enough results in that one partition, it will return that. If there is not enough data in your partition, it will then grow the number of partitions it tries to take until it gets the required number of elements.

Since your RDD is already cached, and your operation is only a map function, as long as any of your RDDs have >5 rows, this will only ever require one task. More tasks would be unnecessary.

This code exists to avoid overloading the driver with too much data by fetching from all partitions at once for a small take.

Comment: Yes this ended up being the case. The strange thing is that with the way I do my analyses (interactively) similar situations have come up regularly but this is the first time it only gave me 1 task.