# what factors affect how many spark job concurrently

Tags: apache-spark

We recently have set up the [Spark Job Server](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) to which the spark jobs are submitted.But we found out that our 20 nodes(8 cores/128G Memory per node) spark cluster can only afford 10 spark jobs running concurrently.

Can someone share some detailed info about what factors would actually affect how many spark jobs can be run concurrently? How can we tune the conf so that we can take full advantage of the cluster?

Comment: I think perhaps you didn't get an answer to the question because the problem is not stated very clearly. What do you mean only 10 jobs can be run? What happens when you try to run 11 jobs? Also, why do you feel like you are not currently taking full advantage of the cluster? Is the CPU utilization too low? Spark can run a single job in parallel on all of your machines. So if your jobs do not run in parallel, that is not a sign of any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is missing some context, but first - it seems like **Spark Job Server** limits the number of concurrent jobs (unlike Spark itself, which puts a limit on number of *tasks*, not jobs):

From [application.conf](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/job-server/src/main/resources/application.conf#L77)

```
 # Number of jobs that can be run simultaneously per context
 # If not set, defaults to number of cores on machine where jobserver is running
 max-jobs-per-context = 8
```

If that's not the issue (you set the limit higher, or are using more than one context), then the total number of cores in the cluster (8*20 = 160) is the maximum number of concurrent *tasks*. If each of your jobs creates 16 tasks, Spark would queue the next incoming job waiting for CPUs to be available.

Spark creates a task per *partition* of the input data, and the number of partitions is decided according to the partitioning of the input on disk, or by calling `repartition` or `coalesce` on the RDD/DataFrame to manually change the partitioning. Some other actions that operate on more than one RDD (e.g. `union`) may also change the number of partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Some things that could limit the parallelism that you're seeing:

- If your job consists of only map operations (or other shuffle-less operations), it will be limited to the number of partitions of data you have. So even if you have 20 executors, if you have 10 partitions of data, it will only spawn 10 task (unless the data is splittable, in something like parquet, LZO indexed text, etc).
- If you're performing a take() operation (without a shuffle), it performs an exponential take, using only one task and then growing until it collects enough data to satisfy the take operation. ([Another question similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766418/spark-map-is-only-one-task-while-it-should-be-parallel-pyspark/34773068#34773068))

Can you share more about your workflow? That would help us diagnose it.